# Why is My TCP Istio EnvoyFilter Not Working?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

I am trying to set TCP idleTimeout via an Envoy Filter, so that outbound connections external domain `some.app.com` will be terminated if they are idle for 5s:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: listener-timeout-tcp
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
      listener:
        filterChain:
          sni: some.app.com
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        name: envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy
        typed_config:
          '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.tcp_proxy.v2.TcpProxy
          idle_timeout: 5s
```

However, when I try to apply this filter I get the following error:

```
Error from server: error when creating "filter.yaml": admission webhook "pilot.validation.istio.io" denied the request: configuration is invalid: envoy filter: missing filters
```

So, I realised that the EnvoyFilter configuration above is not supported by `istio 1.2.5`, so I modified the configuration to work with the old version:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: tcp-idle-timeout
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: mecha-dev
  filters:
    - listenerMatch:
        listenerType: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
        listenerProtocol: TCP
      filterName: envoy.tcp_proxy
      filterType: NETWORK
      filterConfig:
        idle_timeout: 5s
```

After modifying the EnvoyFilter was created but it does not seem to have any affect on the outbound requests. Also, I couldn't find a way to restrict this filter to only outbound requests going to external service `some.app.com`.

Is there something missing in my EnvoyFilter configuration? Also, can we restrict this filter to just `some.app.com`? There's `address` option under `listenerMatch` but what if the IP address of the external service keeps on changing?

Istio and EnvoyProxy version used:

```
ISTIO_VERSION=1.2.5
ENVOY_VERSION=1.11.0-dev
```

Comment: Hello @bakadevops. Could you please tell us which version of Istio are you using?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor the Istio version is ```1.2.5``` and the envoy version it uses is ```1.11.0-dev```.

Comment: You should upgrade to the latest version, support for 1.2 ended in Dec 2019

Comment: @ChristophRaab I realised that this EnvoyFilter configuration does not work because it is not supported y version ```1.2.5```. Yes, upgrading istio will help but, it is an old production cluster so, I cannot do that now. Is there any other work around to make it work?

Comment: You can use the old docs and modify your filter to work with the old api: https://istio.io/v1.2/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/envoy-filter/

Comment: @ChristophRaab I modified the filter and it was created successfully but seems to have no effect. I have updated the question with my modified filter configuration. Is there something missing in it? Thanks.

Comment: I guess the EnvoyFilter config is wrong. Run ``istioctl dashboard envoy mecha-dev`` and get the envoy dump. There you can see, if the config is used.

Comment: any update? replied you also on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1062044/why-is-my-istio-envoyfilter-with-tcp-idle-timeout-setting-isnt-working#comment1383839_1062044)

Comment: @Vitalii I couldn't make the filter work. I checked the envoy dump and it is not being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer. Feel free to expand it.

As already discussed in the comments, the `EnvoyFilter` was not yet supported in Istio version 1.2 and actually that version is no longer in support since Dec 2019.

I strongly recommend upgrading to the latest Istio and Envoy versions. Also, after you upgrade please notice that the filter name you want to use was [deprecated and replaced](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/version_history/v1.14.0#deprecated). You should now use `envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy` instead of `envoy.tcp_proxy`.

Please remember that things are getting deprecated for a reason and keeping the old versions will sooner or later bring you more trouble. Try to keep things more up-to-date.

More details can be found in the [latest docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/).